# Activemq messaging rate

Tags: java, performance, activemq-classic

I will be using activemq for a project and wanted to be able to stress test the application. In which way can I send x number of messages per second so that I can account for a normal period of messaging and see how it handles an abnormal rate of messaging also?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow one of the advices from the activemq [Performance Testing](http://activemq.apache.org/performance.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

As activeMQ is a real time messaging mechanism so everyone should know about its performance
Weather you are using a queue or topic , I suggest you to **use JMeter for its performance testing**. **[please follow this link](http://activemq.apache.org/jmeter-performance-tests.html)** here you will know about everything about **JMeter** and its performance testing.
 Hope it helps :)